# Why doesn't my bot of sending Emails using smtplib work?

Tags: python, smtp

see the code below, every time i try to use this function, it does not work and i kinda don't know why, so somebody could give me a hand?

```
import smtplib

def send_email():
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.hotmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()

server.login('bot_piloto.test@hotmail.com', '*******')

subject = 'You have to see this, it is about your university'
body = 'look, these are yours pendenting homeworks: ' + name_teacher2 + ' and these are yours expired homeworks: '+ name_teacher
sender: 'bot_piloto.test@hotmail.com'
receiver: 'bot_piloto.test@hotmail.com'

msg =  f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

server.sendmail(
    sender,
    receiver,
    msg
)

server.quit()
```

Comment: what does this mean? ... `it does not work`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty different from your original code, but this is the method thay I've found works for me. Use it or don't, but this method is pretty reliable.

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import ssl

def send_email():
    subject = 'You have to see this, it is about your university'
    body = 'look, these are yours pendenting homeworks: ' + name_teacher2 + ' and these are yours expired homeworks: '+ name_teacher
    sender = 'bot_piloto.test@hotmail.com'
    receiver = 'bot_piloto.test@hotmail.com'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = receiver

    body = MIMEText(body, "plain")
    msg.attach(body)

    #Create secure connection with server and send email
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.hotmail.com", 587, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender, "*******")
        server.sendmail(
            sender,
            receiver,
            msg.as_string()
        )
```

Comment: that's not the problem dude. It was just wrong pasting of the code...

Comment: hey, when you defined context = context, what did you do there?

Comment: If you look in the line above that, you can see that I set context equal to ``ssl.create_default_context()`` This is just creating a SSLContext object with default settings. An SSLContext object is an engine class for an implementation of a secure socket protocol. So its basically just making the connection more secure.